# Switching between viewControllers in Xcode

Tags: xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am writing a splash screen. The splash screen would connect to the server and receive some data. When the data has been received successfully, I want to programmatically go to the next viewcontrller. How can I achieve this? Its not the same as button click? Because I dont get forwarded to my next screen even when I put the code in my viewDidLoad of my LoadingViewContrller.

```
TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
tvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:tvc animated:NO];
```

I would like to jump to TableViewContrller automatically after all my data has been retrieved.

Below are my codes when I am retrieving data from the network.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
if(responseData == nil){
    [ErrorViewController showError];
}else{
 //methods to start parsing and adding json into array
if(delegate){
    [delegate jsonReceivedData:array]; 

//codes to go to next screen should be here
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a way to check for when all the data has been retrieved?  If so, please post that code, and I will show you how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the way to do this is simple.  Make the first screen for your app the same as the splash screen.  Declare and instantiate an NSTimer, possibly in viewWillAppear, like so:

```
mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then instantiate a BOOL:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
if(responseData == nil){
    [ErrorViewController showError];
}else{
 //methods to start parsing and adding json into array
if(delegate){
    [delegate jsonReceivedData:array]; 

    myBool = YES;
}
}
```

In the method accessed by your timer (in this case "updateTime") do the following:

```
-(void)updateTime{
    if(myBool){
        [mainTimer invalidate];
        MyViewController *vC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
        //pass vC information, now that it has been initialized
        //or pass information to a singleton, from which vC can retrieve it
        // (I can show you how to do that, too, if need be)
        //I will assume you are using a navigationController
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

For the sake of space, I'm leaving out the declarations of `mainTimer` and `myBool`.

Comment: Assuming by "splash screen" you mean the initial screen of the app.